# C# String elemenths range ":" equivalent

Tags: c#, string

Is it possible to fastly display a String elemenths range like in Python with ":" Thanks!

E.g.

```
Python
s="abazvbn"
print(s[2:5]) //It will display string elemenths from 2 to 5 ('azvb')
```

C#
Is it possible to do it in C# with out using the loop. As currently it is possible to do it like this

```
String s="abazvbn"
for(int i=2;i<5;i++)
COnsole.WriteLine(s[i])
```

Answer (score 4):

Similarly, you have the [`String.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. The parameters are slightly different. You pass in the starting index and the length of the substring you want returned.

Or you can create a `Slice()` extension method. Put it in a static class.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Slice(this string s, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
    int length = endIndex - startIndex + 1;               // Calculate length
    return s.Substring(startIndex, length); // Return Substring of length
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this...

```
string mystring = "abazvbn";
string myslice = mystring.Splice(2, 5);//myslice is azvb
```

Comment: It should be noted that `String.Substring()` is a pretty touchy method - if you overrun the length of the string, you get rewarded with a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.  Python's a lot more forgiving.

Comment: Well, perhaps you want it to be touchy. If not, then sure, rework it to be more pythonic (I can't recall all the Python syntax off the top of my head).

Comment: Or use LINQ, something like `s.Skip(2).Take(5 - 2)` would not crash if the values are out of range.

Comment: Or a `SafeSubstring` extension method, which is one of those things that I imagine exists in approximately half a jillion toolboxes.